# how to convert hascode to string value

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

how can i convert has code value to  string value this is e example has-code value

> a21a239522332080e078fb05bef9420b

i can  convert it using  select command ??

Comment: which SQL Server version it is?

Comment: It is still not clear what do you want to achieve. You have a binary *hash* as a database field and do you want to select its *hex* encoded representation?

Comment: this is a password field , now i want to be see password

Comment: SQL server version  2012

Comment: The idea of hashcode is that you can't convert back

Comment: If you are able to recover a password from the hash, you're doing it wrong. It's also very likely that it's just a MD5 hash (it's 32 hex digits long) for which attacks have been published for quite a few years. Really, if it's a password storage column, you have a **very** serious security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to get the password's original string using only it's hash. Is that correct ?

The hashing process is **irreversible**. Hashes are used to compare initial values, but not to retrieve them.

Say you have an initial value `password` and it's hash would be `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99` (MD5) for example.

The value `password` could be retrieved using Brute Force, where you would have to keep generating values, hashing them with the same hash-function and then comparing to the one you have (`5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`).

If they match - the chances are very high, that `password` is the initial value.